# How to create SEQUENCE for GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example

```
CREATE  GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GGT_temp_reversal 
(                        
  sessionid  VARCHAR  (50)    NULL,                      
  syspk                    NUMERIC  (23)
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS ;

CREATE SEQUENCE GGT_temp_reversal_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GGT_temp_reversal_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON GGT_temp_reversal 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.id IS NULL)
BEGIN
  :new.id := GGT_temp_reversal_seq.NEXTVAL;
END;
```

Getting error "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: There is no column `ID` in the table `GGT_temp_reversal`

Comment: Please set answer as accepted if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating trigger for an ID column

> :new.id := GGT_temp_reversal_seq.NEXTVAL;

But you haven't declared it in CREATE TABLE

```
  CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GGT_TEMP_REVERSAL (
  SESSIONID VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  SYSPK     NUMERIC(23)
  )
```

Add an ID column and it will be fine